# Repeated queries to MySQL backend in Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm looking at my views with django debug toolbar and I noticed that for every request Django starts with the following two queries:

- `SELECT @@SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL`
- `SELECT VERSION()`

I guess these are some kind of "feature detection" queries, however I find it weird that they are executed at *every request*. My first try to solve this was to enable persistent connections (`DATABASES['default']['CONN_MAX_AGE'] = None`) together with [django-mysqlpool](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysqlpool) however it doesn't seem to solve the problem.

My question is:

- is this a (potential) performance bug? Would it make sens to report it to the Django project?
- has anyone solved this successfully (as in eliminating this two initial queries)? If so, how?

Some more details: I'm using Django 1.10.2 running under Google Appengine with CloudSQL (their hosted MySQL solution)